# My server file in Java RMI stops after 2-4 sec from running it on NetBeans with Win8

Tags: java, netbeans, server, rmi

I am trying to build distributed application with Java RMI and I have done a lot of practice and study in these field. So many examples worked just fine.
the Code here is for the server side and it works no problems whatsoever when I run the app through cmd but it shuts down after 2-4 sec before it binds the service just like that, because of this the Client give a "NOTBOUND Exception". and the crazy part is that the same code worked very smoothly in anthor app.

Here is all the codes I am using

RInterface.java

```
package rmi;
import java.rmi.*;
public interface RInterface extends Remote {
public boolean log(String Uname, String code) throws RemoteException;
}
```

RClass.java

```
package rmi;

import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class RClass extends UnicastRemoteObject implements RInterface {

private Connection connect = null;
private Statement statement = null;
private ResultSet resultSet = null;
private boolean stat = false;
public String state = "Waiting Confirmation ...";

public RClass() throws RemoteException {
    super();
    connect();
}


public boolean log(String Uname, String code) throws RemoteException {
    try {
            String sql = "select name,code from logusers where name='"+Uname+"' and code ='"+code+"'";
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);

            int count=0;

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                count+=1;
            }

            if (count==0) {
                 stat = false;
                 state = "NO User Found!! Access Denied";
            }else
                if (count>1) {
                    stat = false;
                    state = "duplicate User!! NOT allowed";
                }else
                    if (count == 1){
                        stat = true;
                        state = "WelCome "+ Uname +"!! Access Granted";
                    }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        }
    return stat;
}

public final void connect(){
    try{ 
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/eysa?"+"user=root&password=");
     statement = connect.createStatement();

    } catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
}
```

myServer.java (my source of pain)

```
package rmi;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class myServer {
myServer() {
    new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                RInterface stub = new RClass();  
                Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost/LOGIN",stub);
            } catch(RemoteException e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(myServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }.start();
}  

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    myServer myS = new myServer();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Server is Ready...");
}
}
```

myClient.java is very simple code and I think no need to attach it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you are exiting vi the `System.exit()` call in your otherwise empty exception handler.

Don't write code like this. When you catch an exception, print or log the exception, or better still the stack trace. Then debugging won't be a mere guessing game.

NB one JDBC Connection and one Statement are not adequate for an RMI server. RMI is automatically multi-threaded. You need a Connection and Statement per remote method invocation.